# Loop and set value for coulmns

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using the set value method to copy data from multiple workbooks. I can currently loop through all workbooks and set the values from one sheet, worksheet2(Title) as seen below, and copy them to "thisWorkbook" on "sheet1", my destination. How can I loop through worksheets 3 to 9 and copy the range A2:C57 into columns G,H,I using the same set value method?

```
Sub GetData()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim SheetName As String
Dim NewRow As Long

MyPath = "C:\attach"
SheetName = "Title"

FileName = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xlsx")
Do While FileName <> ""
 If FileName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 NewRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

 With .Range("A" & NewRow)
 .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B4"
 .Value = .Value
End With
With .Range("B" & NewRow)
 .Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B5"
 .Value = .Value
End With
With .Range("C" & NewRow)
.Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B6"
.Value = .Value
End With
With .Range("D" & NewRow)
.Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!B7"
.Value = .Value
End With
With .Range("E" & NewRow)
.Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!A1"
.Value = .Value
End With
With .Range("F" & NewRow)
.Formula = "='" & MyPath & "\[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!A2"
.Value = .Value
End With

'Copy the range A2:C57 from workheets (3 to 9) and past into columns G,H,I in thisworkbook from every workbook in folder.
'For sheets 3 to 9 set the value range A2:C57 to G,H,I in thisworkbook. This would be done for every workbook in the folder

End With
End If
FileName = Dir

Loop
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: `for i=3 to 9 | with thisworkbook.sheets(i)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking, but I think the range.copy is what you want.

To get the entire worksheet 3-9 you can use

```
' A2:C57 = Cells (2,1),Cells(57,3)
For Sheetindex= 3 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'Copy Worksheet 3 A2:C57

Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets(Sheetindex).Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(57,3)) 

' Paste it in Columns G,H,I starting in Row 1.  


SourceRange.Copy (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("G1")) 

Next Sheetindex
```